A movie with a collector
I don't know the movie name but here's a short description about the beginning: 
There is a guy that had been collecting things since he was a kid. His grandmother gives him a photo of his grandfather with another woman. 
After this part, a family is shown, the father, the grandfather, the son and the mother. 
The father punches the son in slow motion, then a scene comes where the son wearing red clothes, and break-dancing.

I believe the movie is "Everything is Illuminated". The hero is a collector, and travels to find the woman that saved his grandfather during World War II. There is a scene where she gives him a photo of his grandfather with the woman that saved him.
The search that I used was "grandmother gives him picture of grandfather with another woman". 

Very smart of you :p
